# Java regular expression to find links with folders that end with /

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find links with folders that end with '/' e.g. www.w3.org/TR/owl-features/ using java regular expressions but I am unable to do so. any helpp would be appreciated
Here's my code

```
File file4 = new File("W3C Web Pages");
        File[] listOfFiles4 = file4.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles4.length; i++)
        {
          if (listOfFiles4[i].isFile())
          {
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader("W3C Web Pages/"+listOfFiles4[i].getName());    
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(filereader);   
            Pattern regx = Pattern.compile("(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");

            String text;
              while ((text = br.readLine()) != null)
              {
                  Matcher linkswslash = regx.matcher(text);
                  if (linkswslash.find())
                  {
                      if(linkswslash.group().contains("/"))
                      {   
                          System.out.println("Found value: " + linkswslash.group());

                      }

                  }

              }

          }

        }
```

Comment: _"I am unable to do so"_ is insufficient explanation.  There are several excellent online resources for testing regular expressions, have you looked at one of those to experiment and try solving the problem yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change your regex to end in "/", where other url's won't match that don't end in "/". Something like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in here");
        String text = "https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-features/";
        // wont' match https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-features
        // but will match https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-features/
        Pattern regx = Pattern.compile("(https?|ftp|file)://.*\\/$");
        Matcher linkswslash = regx.matcher(text);
        if (linkswslash.find()){
            System.out.println("Found value: " + linkswslash.group());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you escape the ending `/` in the regex?

Comment: Because he wants the url to end in /, since you can't have / in a regex it needs to be delimited and the $ is the end of the line.

Comment: @LloydRochester do u know the regular expression to find links with specific domain like .net or .org?

Comment: can be with or without / at the end

Comment: Would be something like `Pattern regx = Pattern.compile("(https?|ftp|file)://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.(net|org).*");` This will match simple urls that end in net or org and anything at the end.